# change link in text to hyperlink in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm having trouble converting text to a hyperlink in a controller, then sending it to the view.

So far, I have:
Controller:

```
foreach (dynamic tweet in Timeline())
{
    string text = tweet["text"].ToString();
    const string pattern = @"http(s)?://([\w+?\.\w+])+([a-zA-Z0-9\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&amp;\*\(\)_\-\=\+\\\/\?\.\:\;\'\,]*)?";
    Regex regexCheck = new Regex(pattern);

    MatchCollection matches = regexCheck.Matches(text);

    for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
    {
        text = string.Format(@"<a href={0}>{1}</a>", matches[i].Value, matches[i].Value);
    }

    timeline.Add(text);
}
```

View:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Timeline)
```

But It keeps displaying the literal text!
Display: `<a href=http://t.co/fm0ruxjVXe>http://t.co/fm0ruxjVXe</a>`

Could anyone please show me how this is done? I am quite new to MVC.

Comment: As a note- you are missing the " before and after {0}. Should be: <a href=""{0}"">{1}</a>. They are doubled since they have to be escaped.

Comment: Missed that :P Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since you are sending out html already, try

```
 @Html.Raw(Model.Timeline)
```

Another option is to send out just the url and the text and build the a tag in the view

```
 <a href="@Model.Timline.Url">@Model.Timeline.Text</a>
```

That will involve changing your timeline property to being an object with two properties, text and url .

Comment: The 2nd approach sound much better imo.

Comment: Using `@Html.Raw(Model.Timeline[0])` works :) Thanks for the update !

Answer (score 0):

The @Html.DisplayFor helpers in Razor automatically encode the output

If you want to just output the content of model.Timeline, try just using Response.Write